# Why do I sometimes get 401 Unauthorized when I request JIRA Server API?

Tags: excel, vba, jira, winhttp

My goal is consistent response data from JIRA.

Sometimes, the response will succeed with Basic Authentication. Other times I will get a 401 response saying to authenticate using OAuth. I get the 401 response on resources where I have permission.

OAuth doesn't make sense for my application.

The API docs say Basic Authentication is acceptable.
https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.5.13/

Note that this is not JIRA cloud.

```
Set winHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
winHttp.Open "GET", targetURL, False 'false means blocking request 
'targetURL = https://jira.{myOrg}.dev/rest/api/2/filter/{myFilterId}/columns
winHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials
winHttp.send

debug.print winHttp.getAllRequestHeaders
debug.print winHttp.responseText
debug.print winHttp.Status
```

Edit: I get this HTTP Response Header
X-Seraph-LoginReason: AUTHENTICATED_FAILED
The meaning of this header is here: https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-seraph/2.6.1-m1/apidocs/com/atlassian/seraph/auth/LoginReason.html

It says I cannot be Authenticated. So JIRA doesn't recognize my credentials as being a correct pair.

Comment: HTTP 401 "unauthorized" means something different than HTTP 403; looks like your login is working to authenticate, but the authenticated login is not authorized to GET that particular endpoint. Verify server-side API permissions, as applicable.

Comment: I think the problem is not API permissions because my credentials sometimes work for the API on this endpoint, for this same data.

Comment: I have customers who see this sometimes. Not sure why. Jira 8.5.4 Data Center and the jira python library

Answer (score 0):

It looks, like CAPTCHA was triggered, see https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/basic-auth-for-rest-apis/ (last paragraph)

> A CAPTCHA is 'triggered' after several consecutive failed log in attempts, and requires the user to interpret a distorted picture of a word and type that word into a text field with each subsequent log in attempt. If CAPTCHA has been triggered, you cannot use Jira's REST API to authenticate with the Jira site.

> You can check this in the error response from Jira. If there is an X-Seraph-LoginReason header with a value of AUTHENTICATION_DENIED, the application rejected the login without even checking the password. This is the most common indication that Jira's CAPTCHA feature has been triggered.